Is there anything that can be done to shut down the "what is the thing in the picture" questions?
(Solving my own problem by adding identify-tool to my list of ignored tags. I still think that whole topic belongs elsewhere, but as long as I don't have to see it...)


We should declare [identify-a-tool] off-topic and burn the tag. The scope of the site is how to accomplish specific home improvement tasks, and answering "what is this thing I found in a drawer/barn/closet?" is not a home improvement task. Also, half the uses of the tag are about identifying parts, not tools.

We should declare [part-identification] off-topic and burn the tag. It's a meta-tag, not a real tag: it is not a concrete topic that someone can be an expert in. It applies equally to any actual home improvement topic: electrical, plumbing, carpentry, etc. Legitimate questions about identifying a thing (e.g. "this thing is broken, what is it called so I can buy a replacement?") should be tagged with their actual field so they can be directed to experts. As above, "what's this part I found in a drawer" with no other context should be off-topic.

Edit-reviewers should be doing their part by rejecting the mass edits that do nothing but add [part-identification] or [identify-a-tool] to a post. Sub-2K users should not be making tag-only edits, but instead fixing everything that's wrong with a post (fixing typos, removing noise, etc).


